# Using other account when uploading signed apk in google play store

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key, google-api-console

Their is no bug with regard to the maps. I already signed the apk with release keystore ,

the API Keys are registered in my account

It perfectly works in any devices.

What's the problem is when it is uploaded with the client account in google play store 
and downloaded in their device, the map displays white.

Question:

1.Does it affect the application if the API keys are registered to my account and the one who upload the app is not my account ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

The API key is associated with the apk package and it's keystore and not a user account.

First you need to create a keystore for you app. Refer to http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Next go to https://console.developers.google.com/project and create a project (if don't have one already).

On your project page go to **API's & auth** > **APIs** enable  **Google Maps Android API v2**

Next go to  **API's & auth** > **Credentials**  and create a new Key for Android applications. Follow those instructions careful and you it will generate you an API to use on your manifest. (Remember to use the keystore you used to sign your app for play store and not your debug keystore)

More info:

https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys

Good luck

Comment: I already did this. And the app is good to go. But when it is uploaded in the play store with different account the map broke.

Comment: From Google `Google verifies that each request originates from an Android application that matches one of the certificate SHA1 fingerprints and package names listed below.` There is no mention for account. You must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

I also face this problem . you need to

> signed your application with the system from which you generate SHA-1
>   fingerprint for Google Api

.

Comment: You mean signed with the same pc ?

Comment: I already did that, the problem is when it is uploaded in google play and downloaded the map broke.

Answer (score 1):

Check Your API Key whether it is the same with the one in Console and in your Manifest.