# Steps to publish my app on playstore from scratch

Tags: android, google-maps, apk, publishing, google-apps-marketplace

I made an app on google maps. Added API key in my project that I made from google developer console. Can anybody please guide me how to upload apk on playstore? I am asking because I am putting it first time on play store and I should not miss any steps. And since it is related to google maps might be I need to do some extra steps.

I tried to start this using file< export and then three options come. One of which is location with browse button. Which location is to be selected?

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="MY API KEY" />
```

So please gyus help me in this.

Comment: Go through  https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

Comment: video tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wN3JTIZXfk

Comment: but they are saying to make a keystore in which location is one option(with browse) . how to use this?

Comment: @Golinski youtube is banned in my company. we have only google access

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26034501/using-other-account-when-uploading-signed-apk-in-google-play-store) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. export a signed version of your apk by right click on project -> android tool -> signed apk-> follow the procedure
2. save the key store in some secure place, cause its needed for update your application second time.
3. take some screen shoots of your application to publish on play store.

3.create a account on google and upload will take some hours to publish.

Comment: in location which location i need to select?

Comment: where you want to save your keystore

Comment: ok after that window there is another window asking alias name password and confirm password. Is it the same password which was in previous window? and yes once i made the keystore where i need to put that keystore file?

Comment: also what should i put in alias name and what is the use of it? and basically i am using google maps api key in my project so what changes i need to do?

Comment: just put your name is alias name and the password is same as previous, and that keystore is used for future for now there is no use but you have to store it for future use.

Comment: ok apk is generated. is it called signed apk? and yes in my manifest there is google maps api key . So do i need a little bit changes in that key?

Comment: if that is correct whatever you generated from google developer then do not change any thing just upload to google play.

Comment: i made api key for google maps by SHA fingerprint that we get in  Windows> preferences>Android>Build in the following way SHA1;package name. Is it correct(i used it for testing my app)? Then i put that in manifest and made keystore and apk. But in some documents i read that for releasing apk we have to make a diffrent SHA 1 fingerprint by the keystore that we made. I havnt done those steps. Do i need to do those and made api key again with release sha1 fingerprint?

Comment: use keytool -list keystore mykeystore.keystore it gives you a MD5 Certificate fingerprint. then Start an export process to create an apk for your app and use your production key. The very last page displays both your SHA1 and MD5 certificate fingerprints

Comment: is my answer is helpful for you, if yes then accept my answer.

Comment: ok then i put this key in manifest. but then which apk to upload? the one which is formed at the time of making keystore or the one which is now once i put the new sha 1 fingerprint in manifest?

Comment: last one whick you created using sha 1 fingerprint.

Comment: ok so this time i dont need to export it or make a new keystore for map key changes? What i am doing is the new api key i am putting it in manifest and running the program and taking apk (which i need to put on play store)  which is formed in bin folder. If there are any changes please let me know or if i m still wrong.

Comment: no man dont use bin folder apk you have to use signed apk, which ever api key it doesnt matter, just export a signed verson and upload.

Comment: signing it again will ask to make keystore again. I have already made keystore before and with that keystore only i made release key for google maps. Should i make keystore again?

Comment: What are the other things that I should do after publishing an app? I just found out that I have to link my app in admob.

Comment: it depends if you want to monetization then you have to else not required.